# passing icons into a JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons

I have a js file with an array of objects, I am trying to load the attributes dynamically with a component and I cannot seem to figure out how to pass icons to the rendering component.

Here is the component that I am using to render the data:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SkillData from '../../store/skillData';
import './SkillsCard.css';

class SkillsCard extends Component {
    state = { }

    renderSkills = () => 
    SkillData.map((skill, _id) => 
        <div key={_id} className="skillCard col-sm-3 m-2">
            <div className="top">
                {/* ***line in question*** */}
                <div className="icon">{skill.icon}</div>
                <h5>{skill.title}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="bottom">
                    {skill.techs.map((tech,index)=>(
                    <div className='skillCardList' key={index}> {tech}</div>
                    ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    render() { 
    
        return ( 
            this.renderSkills()
         );
    }
}
 
export default SkillsCard;
```

and here is the file that I am pulling data from:

```js
const SkillData = [
    {
        _id: '1',
        icon: '../../assets/icons/frontend.png',
        title: 'Front End',
        techs: ['HTML5', 'CSS | SCSS', 'JavaScript', 'React | Redux', 'Angular']
    },
    {
        _id: '2',
        icon: '../../assets/icons/server.png',
        title: 'Back End',
        techs: ['NodeJS', 'Express', 'Postman', 'Authentication | Authorization']
    },
    {
        _id: '3',
        icon: '../../assets/icons/database.png',
        title: 'Databases',
        techs: ['MongoDB', 'mySQL', 'PostgreSQL']
    }
]

export default SkillData
```

The issue that I am having is that I cannot get the path name to the icons to evaluate and actually render the icon; Instead my component renders the text, listed on the path. All the other attributes render just fine! Any thoughts?

Comment: That's because you are putting the actual icon path in the div tag, in the div tag create an img tag and make it's src `{skill.icon}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're just rendering the string value to the page:

```
<div className="icon">{skill.icon}</div>
```

Did you mean to use an `<img>` element?:

```
<div className="icon">
  <img src={skill.icon} />
</div>
```

Comment: @WesHampton: What do you mean by "the path doesn't evaluate"?  In the question it sounded like the path was successfully rendering as text, and you just needed it to be an image.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I added

```
const icons = require.context('../assets/icons', true);
```

in the SKillData.js file and set the paths to:

```
icons('./iconName.png'),
```

Thanks a million, David!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Direct require from your local assets folder, so you dont need the complexity to head file import a link from a json file request

```
{/* line in question */}
<div className="icon">
  <img src={require(`${skill.icon}`)} />
</div>
```